# unable to select items in object in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

in my redux action i have a fetch that works great. i'm using redux-thunk to dispatch it to my reducer. I then obviously connect my component to the store. within my reactjs component i am able to see the json object. lets say the structure is

```
object:{
    person: {
        name: {
            first: "first",
            last: "last"
    }
  }
}
```

when I try to obtain just the first name like (person.name.first) it says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined" but first is defined. basically any information that is three items deep it gives me the same message.
When looking in my react component the issue is within the console.log(). the issue is happening anywhere within the component that i try to access the same location of the object not just within the console.log().

my Action:

```
import { WEEKWEATHER,
    TODAYWEATHER,
    SEARCH,
    LOCATIONERROR
} from './types';

//autolocate on page load
 export const autoLocate = (location) => {  
 const url = 
 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/cc9e7fcca25e2ded/geolookup/q/' + 
 location + '.json'

 return (dispatch) => {

          fetch(url)
             .then((response) => response.json())
             .then(response => forcast(dispatch, response))
             .catch( (error) => { dispatch({ type:LOCATIONERROR }) })
};
};

//locate with search bar
 export const Locate = (location) => {  
 const url = 
 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/cc9e7fcca25e2ded/geolookup/q/' + 
 location + '.json'

 return (dispatch) => {
 dispatch({type: SEARCH,
          payload: location
          });


          fetch(url)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then(response => forcast(dispatch, response))
            .catch( (error) => { dispatch({ type:LOCATIONERROR }) })

};
};


//gathering forcast data from either auto or typed info
 const forcast = (dispatch, response) => {
 const location = response.location.zip
 const tenDayUrl = 
 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/cc9e7fcca25e2ded/forecast10day/q/' 
 + location + '.json'
    const todayUrl = 
 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/cc9e7fcca25e2ded/hourly/q/' + 
 location + '.json'

 fetch(todayUrl)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then(response => dispatch({
                               type: TODAYWEATHER,
                               payload: response.hourly_forecast[0]
                             }))
   .catch( (error) => { dispatch({ type:LOCATIONERROR }) })


   fetch(tenDayUrl)
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then(response => dispatch({
                                 type: WEEKWEATHER,
                                 payload: 
 response.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0]
                               }))
   .catch( (error) => { dispatch({ type:LOCATIONERROR }) })


 };
```

my reducer:

```
import { TODAYWEATHER,  WEEKWEATHER, LOCATIONERROR, SEARCH } from 
'../Actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE =  {
    week:[],
};
export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case WEEKWEATHER:
        return{ ...state, week:action.payload, loading:false }
                return state;
        }

    };
```

my react componenet:

```
import React, { Component }     from 'react';
import { connect }              from 'react-redux';
import { Locate, autoLocate }   from '../Actions';
import {Card} from './Common'

class Weather extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={

         };
    }
    render() {
        const Loading = <Card>Loading...</Card>

        const Weather =  <div style={styles.PositionColumn}>
                            <div>tuesday</div>
                                <Card>
                                    <div style={styles.flexColumn}>
                                        <div style={styles.flexRow}>
                                            <div>jklsjdfkls</div>
                                            <div>2jlsfjle</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div style={styles.flexRow}>
                                           <div>11</div>
                                            <div>22</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </Card>
                            </div>

        const displayWeather = (this.props.loading === true)? Loading 
: Weather;

        console.log(this.props.week.date.day)

        return(
           <div>
                <img style={styles.Background} src=
{this.state.background} alt=''/>


                    {displayWeather}

            </div>
        );
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    const week = state.locate.week;


        return{ week };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {Locate, autoLocate})(Weather)
```

Comment: Is it by mistake that you've omitted the colons?   person: {name: { first: "first", last: "last"}}

Comment: This is not helpful. You need to show the code. How you are accessing the object and where you are logging the object?

Comment: I appologize i should of added my code to begin with. the question is updated with the code i am having the issue with

Comment: not sure if this was just an example or not but i don't see anywhere in your code the line `person.name.first`

Answer (score 0):

When React components mount, redux always sends the defaultState first. It doesn't matter if if fetch is in `componentWillMount`. That dispatch is not fast enough. You need to fix your initial state in your reducer file so that it has the same template as the actual data.

```
const INITIAL_STATE =  {
   person: {
     name: {
       first: "",
       last: ""
     }
   }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your default state with reducers.

```
const INITIAL_STATE= {person : { name : {} }}
```